# Extent and crs of rasters not written by writeCDF

Tags: raster, netcdf, terra

When writing rasters in netCDF files, I always get the warning message: "[rast] unknown extent". Indeed, the extent is not written in the external file. Neither is the crs.

```
library(terra)
#terra version 1.0.2

r <- rast(ncol=2, nrow=2, vals=c(5.3, 7.1, 3, 1.2))
crs(r)<-"epsg:27572"
ext(r)
#SpatExtent : -180, 180, -90, 90 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

t<-writeCDF(r,"test.ncdf",overwrite=TRUE)
#Warning message:
#[rast] unknown extent
 
ext(t)  # extension is not correct
#SpatExtent : 0, 1, 0, 1 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

crs(t)  # crs is not correct
#[1] "GEOGCRS[\"unknown\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n     ...
```

Perhaps there is a peculiar syntax to use here. I explored `?writeCDF`, but could not find any clue.

Answer (score 2):

This points at an issue with GDAL --- depending on whether you think that `.ncdf` is a common filename extension for netCDF files.

```
library(terra)
#terra version 1.0.3
r <- rast(ncol=2, nrow=2, vals=c(5.3, 7.1, 3, 1.2))
```

Note the different file extensions, `.nc`, `.cdf`, `.ncdf` or missing.

```
# ok
x <- writeCDF(r, "test1.nc", overwrite=TRUE)
y <- writeCDF(r, "test2.cdf", overwrite=TRUE)

# not ok
z <- writeCDF(r, "test3.ncdf", overwrite=TRUE)
#Warning message:
#[rast] unknown extent
a <- writeCDF(r, "test4", overwrite=TRUE)
#Warning message:
#[rast] unknown extent
```

`GDALinfo` shows:

```
describe("test1.nc")[1] 
#[1] "Driver: netCDF/Network Common Data Format"
describe("test3.ncdf")[1]
#[1] "Driver: HDF5Image/HDF5 Dataset"
```

It looks like GDAL first tries the netCDF driver when the extension is `.nc` or `.cdf`, but that it first tries the HDF5 driver when it is `.ncdf` or missing --- and since this does not fail (the warning comes from terra, not from GDAL), that is what it uses.

This is the GDAL version on windows.

```
gdal()
#[1] "3.0.4"
```

I see the same behavior with GDAL 2.2.3 on linux and 3.2.0 on mac.

You can work around that by not using `.ncdf` or by specifying the driver when opening the file:

```
rast('NETCDF:"test3.ncdf"')
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 2, 2, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 180, 90  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#source      : NETCDF:test1.ncdf 
#varname     : test1 
#name        : test1
```

I do not think there is anything wrong with the CRS (it is the same as `crs(r)`). However, I should note that terra writes the proj4 and wkt strings to a ncdf file, and does not follow the ncdf standard in that respect.

(You are asking a question about a method that is only available in the development version of terra. I appreciated that very much, but raising an issue on the [terra github site](https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues) would be more appropriate in this case. I will make writeCDF give a warning when the file extension is not `.nc` or `.cdf`)

Comment: Thanks, it works. Something I do not understand: how can a .ncdf file be correctly read by the NETCDF driver after having been written with an HDF5 driver?

Comment: GDAL is opening it with the HDF5 driver after writing, to return a new SpatRaster object; the file was not written with that driver. `writeCDF` does not use GDAL.

Comment: OK. It is clear. Perhaps the ".ncdf" extension should be removed from the list of automatically recognized file extensions during writing, because it is currently read as HDF5, not netCDF ? It is misleading for the user.